# How to shift multiple columns of data up several rows in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2012, row, shift

I have a query which works (shown below) that loops through a block of rows and shifts *some* of the columns backwards.  Some columns need to be shifted back more rows than others.  I found a method for shifting on this site, but it only shifts one channel.  I don't care about the starting and ending values overwriting.  There must be a more elegant and efficient way.

The reason for shifting, not that it matters, is that I am sampling some emissions and it takes several seconds for that sample to get through a sample line to the analyzer.   In order to correct my emissions calculations, I need to have the sample concentrations shifted back to the moment in time that they were actually drawn.  Data is stored at 1 Hz, so the shifts in this case are 6-7 seconds.

```
DECLARE @RUNNUMBER int
SET @RUNNUMBER = 2063

DECLARE @ROWCOUNT int
SET @ROWCOUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RunNumber = @RUNNUMBER AND CurrentMode > 0)

DECLARE @FIRSTROW int
SET @FIRSTROW = (SELECT MIN(RecID) FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RunNumber = @RUNNUMBER AND CurrentMode > 0)

DECLARE @DOCShift int
SET @DOCShift = 6

DECLARE @DPFShift int
SET @DPFShift = 7

DECLARE @SCRShift int
SET @SCRShift = 7

DECLARE @i int = @FIRSTROW
WHILE @i <= @FIRSTROW + @ROWCOUNT - 1 BEGIN
    UPDATE DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15
        SET 
            [DOC Out Ammonia] = (SELECT [DOC Out Ammonia] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Carbon Dioxide High] = (SELECT [DOC Out Carbon Dioxide High] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Carbon Monoxide Low] = (SELECT [DOC Out Carbon Monoxide Low] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Carbon Monoxide High] = (SELECT [DOC Out Carbon Monoxide High] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Nitric Oxide] = (SELECT [DOC Out Nitric Oxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Nitrogen Dioxide] = (SELECT [DOC Out Nitrogen Dioxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Nitrous Oxide] = (SELECT [DOC Out Nitrous Oxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 
            [DOC Out Propene] = (SELECT [DOC Out Propene] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DOCShift), 

            [DPF Out Ammonia] = (SELECT [DPF Out Ammonia] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Carbon Dioxide High] = (SELECT [DPF Out Carbon Dioxide High] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Carbon Monoxide Low] = (SELECT [DPF Out Carbon Monoxide Low] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Carbon Monoxide High] = (SELECT [DPF Out Carbon Monoxide High] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Nitric Oxide] = (SELECT [DPF Out Nitric Oxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Nitrogen Dioxide] = (SELECT [DPF Out Nitrogen Dioxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Nitrous Oxide] = (SELECT [DPF Out Nitrous Oxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 
            [DPF Out Propene] = (SELECT [DPF Out Propene] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @DPFShift), 

            [SCR Out Ammonia]= (SELECT [SCR Out Ammonia] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Carbon Dioxide High] = (SELECT [SCR Out Carbon Dioxide High] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Carbon Monoxide Low] = (SELECT [SCR Out Carbon Monoxide Low] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Carbon Monoxide High] = (SELECT [SCR Out Carbon Monoxide High] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Nitric Oxide] = (SELECT [SCR Out Nitric Oxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Nitrogen Dioxide] = (SELECT [SCR Out Nitrogen Dioxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Nitrous Oxide] = (SELECT [SCR Out Nitrous Oxide] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift), 
            [SCR Out Propene] = (SELECT [SCR Out Propene] FROM DEERDAQData.dbo.B142C15 WHERE RecID = @i + @SCRShift)    
        WHERE RecID = @i
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

What this would look like is shown below.  I need to do it for multiple channels (columns) in a single query where each channel may shift backward a different number of seconds (rows).  Microsoft SQL Server is the platform.  I need to actually CHANGE the data.  I don't just want to output it to some temporary table.

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC124.png)

Comment: This is a bit confusing, Perhaps add a before/after example of the table.  Can you not simply add a new row with the new data? - Please edit and add a tag for the specific database platform you are using.

Comment: It is (in my experience) always wrong to use a loop in SQL.  You don't say what platform you are using but I expect you want to use `LAG()` or `LEAD()`

Comment: It looks like LEAD() may work, but how do I actually modify the data rather than just selecting it?  All of the LEAD/LAG (first time I've seen these) examples I see just show people selecting some data.  Thank you.